# PHP ImageMagick change color in every frame Animated Gif

Tags: php, imagemagick, animated-gif

I am trying to change RGB values in an animated GIF to another RGB value. However in all my attempts it's only changing the color in one frame instead of all frames.

```php
$imgif = new Imagick(HOME_PATH.'/images/6.gif');
$target = 'rgba(238,131,41, 1.0)';
$fill = 'rgba(163,145,144, 1.0)';
$fuzz = 0.05 * $imgif->getQuantumRange()['quantumRangeLong'];
$imgif->opaquePaintImage($target, $fill, $fuzz, false, Imagick::CHANNEL_DEFAULT);

$imgifblob = $imgif->getImagesBlob();
```

Is there anyway to index a color for the entire GIF and change it? I am rather lost as I don't have much experience with image manipulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I do not know Imagick that well. But here is how to do it in Imagemagick command line. You may have to loop over each frame in Imagick, since it may not allow for multi-frame images to be processing. But perhaps using readImages would work. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.readimages.php, where you specify all frames in the gif as 6.gif[0--1], which is all frames from  frame 0 to the last frame -1. Sorry, I just do not know. An Imagick expert might be able to help further.

Input:

[image]

```
convert bunny_anim.gif -coalesce -fuzz 10% -fill red -opaque "rgb(51,77,204)" -layers optimize new_bunny.gif
```

[image]